# Garden tub pipes emitting foul odor

Tags: plumbing

I have a garden tub that never gets used. There is a foul (not sewage) smell coming from it. What is it and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. What is the tub connected to? A picture might help.

Comment: Is there anything in it, like water, soil, etc.?

Comment: Are you sure the trap hasn't gone dry, given that you "never use it"?

Comment: When I run the tub there is a rust colored debris that comes out with the water but I figured that was just from hardly running it.  The odor seems to come from the drain, not the faucet. It could be because it gets dry. Other than running it regularly, is there a way to get rid of the smell or could there be a bigger problem?

Comment: Where does the drain go?  Sewer or somewhere else?

Comment: It goes to our septic system and we have no issue with any other drains

Answer (score 1):

I think the trap is dry.   Run at least a half gallon (2 litres) of water down the drain and see if that stops the odor.